# Why do two charts (Table and Bar Chart) display different data?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a strange issue in Google Data Studio where stacked column/bar charts are not displaying data correctly. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm setting it up or a bug. I've linked the Google Sheet and data page below.

[Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGNdFDLbel3rA1gzVRUmuNuMnJVzu_gPdZtTECTasVk/edit?usp=sharing):

| Date | Roll | Roller |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/2022 | 12 | Oscar |
| 1/5/2022 | 11 | Oscar |
| 1/6/2022 | 10 | Oscar |
| 1/7/2022 | 3 | Oscar |
| 1/8/2022 | 1 | Oscar |
| 1/9/2022 | 5 | Oscar |
| 1/10/2022 | 18 | Dusty |
| 1/11/2022 | 14 | Oscar |
| 1/12/2022 | 14 | Oscar |
| 1/13/2022 | 14 | Oscar |
| 1/14/2022 | 3 | Dusty |
| 1/15/2022 | 2 | Dusty |
| 1/16/2022 | 14 | Oscar |
| **1/17/2022** | **14** | **Chris** |
| 1/18/2022 | 8 | Oscar |
| 1/19/2022 | 9 | Oscar |
| 1/20/2022 | 14 | Oscar |
| **1/21/2022** | **7** | **Chris** |
| 1/22/2022 | 10 | Alex |

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a04ee693-13ca-459c-a967-62e51bcb7709)

As seen "Chris" has two `Roll` inputs (14 and 7) on the table but in the graph it's only showing one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Bar Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560), the default number of "*Series*" (unique values in the Breakdown Dimension field, in this case, the field titled `Roll`)  is set to 10 and can be changed from the Style tab (with the current maximum of 20, which will be sufficient in this scenario as the `Roll` field has a [`COUNT_DISTINCT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583428) value of 12).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f393c2c5-7ab0-4114-a1ea-073a80f63190) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HcF4a5JabRKRTTPKB5oNw5HKDXKjxe7cyKUAf3lqSXU/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because you're using No. series default of the bar while the number of series in your data is higher than this default. So, there is only the top series are shown. You can see more detail [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

Comment: **NOTE**: The issue in this case was to do with a default setting and is NOT related to hidden spaces, thus using the [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583446?hl=en) function will NOT resolve the issue. "*In a [Bar Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560), the default number of "*Series*" (unique values in the Breakdown Dimension field, in this case, the field titled `Roll`)  is set to 10 and can be changed from the Style tab (with the current maximum of 20)*". [See Answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72041475/12892553)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).